# Не получается открыть в браузере rails сервер

Tags: linux, ruby-on-rails, сервер, ruby

Создаю сервер на Linux Ubuntu
Последовательность команд следующая:

```
$ gem install rails
$ rails new blog
$ cd blog
$ rails server
```

После этого пытаюсь перейти по ссылке:  http://localhost:3000
И получаю следующее: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так

Comment: А `htop` показывает, что есть дерево, в котором `rails` чё-то там выполняет?

Comment: Последняя команда должна вывести всю нужную информацию - нужно лишь её прочесть... или выложить сюда :)